# Uncaught TypeError in console when reading an input value

Tags: javascript

Saving input value causes "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')", even if it's not empty. App works ok, if input is empty it doesn't save anything into object (as it should), but it causes this error which is really annoying. How to prevent this error or just don't read read an empty input?

I'm using:

```
userData.firstAndLastName = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

I've tried placing if statement before (if null don't do nothing), but it doesn't work.

Comment: The error means that `document.getElementById()` is returning `null`, meaning that the code finds no element with id "name" in the document.